# Does Keras support sparse TF_CONFIG for elastic training

Tags: tensorflow, keras

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ClusterSpec

Each job may also be specified as a sparse mapping from task indices to network addresses. This enables a server to be configured without needing to know the identity of (for example) all other worker tasks:

```
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"worker": {1: "worker1.example.com:2222"},
                                "ps": ["ps0.example.com:2222",
                                       "ps1.example.com:2222"]})
```

Dose Keras support this?

How Keras support elastic training.